# UIPopoverPresentationController : ActionSheet position at barButtonItem (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, uiactionsheet, uipopover

I have an `UIAlertController` (`UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`) on iPhone which now should be presented in a `UIPopoverPresentationController` on the iPad version..

I am doing the following:

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = sectionActionSheet.popoverPresentationController;
if (popover){
    popover.sourceView = self.view;
    popover.barButtonItem = menuButton;
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
}
```

Unfortunately the position of the popover (in relation to the UIBarButton) is not so nice and if I rotate the device the popover is not repositioned:

**Corner not centered:** 
[image]

**After rotate:**
[image]